# Best microcontroller for industrial applications

Tags: microcontroller, pic, avr, arm, msp430

I have an industrial project requirement to build a device having this functionality:

- Store Data
- Send Data to Web Server
- Device to be placed under scorching sun
- Sensors - around 5
- A Graphical Dashboard
- RFID authentication
- Buzzer

And maybe a couple more. I am totally getting confused which microcontroller to use:

- MSP430
- ATMEL
- PIC
- ARM (Cortex)
- etc

Or others but I am not sure - I presume that there are other families also for my aid which I don't know. So which microcontroller should I use based upon performance, storage, durability, speed, architecture and robustness?

Comment: The one you know how to develop for. Almost all manufacturers have competing parts.

Comment: Thoroughly study them. But the most important aspect is, which toolchain/IDE/datasheet style suits you best.

Comment: your list of "microcontrollers" varies wildly from a model from Texas Instruments (MSP430), to a whole company (Atmel) to a range of models from Microchip (PIC), to an international standard of core design (ARM), and the subset of this (Cortex). and etc shows less research than is acceptable to be given a non-primarily-opinion based answer..

Comment: I agree as my knowledge and non-availability of these MCU presently at my desk. In general which is most preferred one?

Comment: How much is the data? What is your sensor? or at least through which way you should read data? I mean do the sensors have any intereface(SPI, I2C,...)? or you should use ADC or... have you worked with ethernet protocol so far? I don't think the 8bits would be suitable for your job. if I were you, I would choose a MCU that has the DMA unit.

Comment: As reference [http://stackoverflow.com/q/26294686/1790864](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26294686/1790864)

Comment: Data needs to stored in a storage device to be uploaded and flushed later any time in a day. No the sensors would not have any interface, yes I need ADC,Serial, GPIO, GPRS, GSM and around 5 general purpose sensors. It should also sustain to high heat say something around 60 degree Celsius. So which controller would best - sorry my knowledge related to MCU and its functionalities is very limited. My request is to suggest the best micro controller for the project.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Which micro-controller should I use based upon 
>   performance, storage, durability, speed , architecture and robustness?

To that list add
availability,
second sourcing,
cost,
remaining lifetime before obsoleted,
support,
cost of entry to development (hardware, compilers,
familiarity with language or hardware,
and any other factors that are of more than trivial relevance to you.

Then decide relative importance of various parameters to you and give each a value from say 1 to 10.

Choose candidate processors that appear to be able to do the job.
For volume production only, you COULD subset at this stage based on costing within the range you can justify for volume purchasing.

Score each candidate roughly according to how they seem to match your criteria.

Order in list of declining score.

Decide if there is any obvious good reason not to discard the bottom half of the list.
Discard bottom half :-).

Look at top few candidates.
If one has a stand out score relative to all challengers, more carefully score the top say 3 again.
If there is still a standout, decide to probably use it, and ask sales rep for each why you should use theirs :-).

If no standout, choose one that you feel happiest with for reasons that seem good to you and use it.

---

If that is a one off or few off application, and maybe even if a many off,
then if [this "Internet of things" device](https://www.spark.io/) will do what you want, consider using it.

Spark Core - Open source software, open source hardware, open source 'cloud' presence, ARM based, Arduino compatible, WiFi on board.
A person conversant with the genal areas involved can have one of these doing useful things via the internet in (well) under an hour.

Features: https://www.spark.io/features

---

AND it looks good ...

[image]

PS: I have no involvement with Spark Core. I have one sitting on my desk as I type - as yet unused. Any day now.